# How to write Nested Enum Code For the Data Bases and their tables and columns corrosponding

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, enums

i am developing my project in which a large data base which has no of data bases and the tables, columns have

so my plan is to do somthing like if in future i have to change my database name or table name or columns name so i make changes only one place and all the changes done automatically where the DB name table or columns name has been used.

then i have to decided using enum for that hence enum should be nested and each property can have its string value so that only changes in the string value can change its all places where it has been used

```
so please help me some buddy to give me some sample of code samll code by which i can do it for my database 

eg DATABASE->TABLE->COLUMNS
public enum DATABASE
{
    //
}

i want enum sample code for database and nested enums for their tables and one of its  nested enum for their columns please help me...!!! 

i have tried it to find it but not got some thing usefull
```

ok i got my answer
here is

```
public enum DATABASE
{
  DB1(TABLE.TBL1, TABLE.TBL2);

  private final TABLE[] tblArray;
  private DATABASE(TABLE... tables)
  {
    tblArray = tables;
  }
  public TABLE[] getTables()
  {
    return tblArray;
  }
}
public enum TABLE
{
  TBL1(COLUMN.CLMN1, COLUMN.CLMN2), TBL2(COLUMN.CLMN2);

  private final COLUMN[] clmnArray;
  private TABLE(COLUMN... columns)
  {
    clmnArray = columns;
  }
  public COLUMN[] getColumns()
  {
    return clmnArray;
  }
}
public enum COLUMN
{
  CLMN1, CLMN2;
}
```

actually i am not perfect in enum so please tell me how to access the DATABASE , TABLE and COLUMN means if i want DB1->TB1->CLMN2 so how to write code ...

Comment: If you use `JPA` or `Hibernate` you can declare an annotation `@Table` that will give the table name, so there is already only one place when you have to change it. Same for `@Column`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i want enum sample code for database and nested enums for their tables and one of its nested enum for their columns please help me...!!!

Comment: actually its boundation for me that i can use JPA or hibernet because i have Apache Tomcat 5.5 web server which does not support and have to use JDBC API

Comment: Outside that I consider this a bad idea ... I think what you want to use are public static inner classes. You can make your `DATABASE` class abstract, so it cannot be instantiated. Inside you create a public static class TABLE in which you can define constants (public static final String COL_THISANDTHAT = "StringConstantColName" ).

Comment: ok i got the way what you mean ,.....thank you so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not with enums, but I think what you want:

```
public abstract class DATABASE
{
   public static class TABLE_ONE
   {
       public static final String NAME = "TableOne";
       public static final String COL_ONE = "COLUMN_ONE";
       public static final String COL_TWO = "COLUMN_TWO";
   }
}
```

You can use it like `DATABASE.TABLE_ONE.COL_ONE` and so on.

Why I think this is dangerous: If you change Constants here, you'll have to handle DB-Updates also and mind people upgrading from one version of your software to another. So be careful!

Comment: ok i have already done it and its also a best way.... thanks for help me thank you so much

Comment: Then please consider accepting this answer :) (Click the hook on the side. It will turn green) That's the way we reward good answers on SO. It will also rise your "accepted answers" ratio, which will motivate others to put effort in answering your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
public enum DATABASE
{
    DB1(TABLE.TBL1, TABLE.TBL2);

    private final TABLE[] tblArray;
    private DATABASE(TABLE... tables)
    {
        tblArray = tables;
    }
    public TABLE[] getTables()
    {
        return tblArray;
    }
}
public enum TABLE
{
    TBL1(COLUMN.CLMN1, COLUMN.CLMN2), TBL2(COLUMN.CLMN2);

    private final COLUMN[] clmnArray;
    private TABLE(COLUMN... columns)
    {
        clmnArray = columns;
    }
    public COLUMN[] getColumns()
    {
        return clmnArray;
    }
}
public enum COLUMN
{
    CLMN1, CLMN2;
}
```

Comment: ok actually i am not perfect in enum so please tell me how to access the DATABASE , TABLE and COLUMN means if i want DB1->TB1->CLMN2 so how to write code ...

Comment: as it is mentioned while defining enums itself, there's no need to be concerned about which one to choose while accessing. Once we know we need to use DB1, we can get all related tables and their columns, using `DB1.getTables()` and for each table's `TABLE.getColumns()` using looping through arrays. Once we retireve them we can check if they are equal to a particular TABLE or COLUMN like TB1 or CLMN2. If you just need access facility using dot notation, you should consider using classes rather than nested enums as suggested by other's answer

Comment: ok if it is so this way will be more complecated what your opinion i mean according to you what should i do,...i should choose static class or enum

Comment: then static classes is a better way, and use enums only for constants at a single level. you can consider using enums at innermost level for example for column names

Comment: ok thanks buddy...you have solved my problem in such a wonderful way thanks again